# Writing to the line in Reverse Order

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

I want to write the lines in reverse order like
Input: line 1.line 2.line 3.
Output: line 3. line 2. line 1.

This is the following code.

```
{            
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/file/in.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("src/file/out.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String msg =buffer.readLine();
    String[] words = msg.split ("\\.");
    System.out.println( "The reversed words are : ");
    for(int x = words.length - 1; x >=0; x--) {
        bw.write(words[x] + " "); 
    } 
    bw.close();
    fr.close();
}
```

Comment: "here it is not working" define not working. Do words appear when you print them on console? Do you close `bw` and `buffer` after you iterate over entire text you wanted to parse?

Comment: it is printing on console. i haven't closed . let me check

Comment: you are just reading first line. Is it OK?

Comment: Is it multiple lines or words?

Comment: multiple lines which consist of multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

Close the stream

```
       try {            
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("in.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("out.txt");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String msg =buffer.readLine();
            String[] words = msg.split (" ");
            System.out.println( "The reversed words are : ");
            for(int x = words.length - 1; x >=0; x--) {
                bw.write(words[x] + " ");  // here it is not working
               // System.out.print(words[x]+" " );
            }
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush it before you close it.

```
for(int x = words.length - 1; x >=0; x--) {
   bw.write(words[x] + " ");  // here it is not working
   // System.out.print(words[x]+" " );
}
bw.flush() ; // this should do it
bw.close() ;
fr.close() ;
```

Comment: Java flushes streams when they are closed. While flush the stream will write it to disk, in this case it is a little redundant.

Comment: So flush won't help ?

Comment: I think most streams do flush when they close. For buffered writers they do. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close() While the flush won't help, you want to get into the habit to flush after you've w finished ritten your data

Comment: when u do close its automatically flushed

Answer (score 0):

If you uses [Java 7 -The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) then there is no need to close or flush the stream. It's by default handled even in case of any Exception.

Use `Collections.reverse` to reverse the order of any array/list.

sample code:

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.txt"));
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"))) {

    String msg = null;
    while ((msg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        String[] words = msg.split(" ");
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(words));
        String reversedString = Arrays.toString(words);
        reversedString = reversedString.substring(1, reversedString.length()-1);
        System.out.println("The reversed words are : " + reversedString);
        writer.write(reversedString);
        writer.newLine();
    }
}
```

[Read more...](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/trywithresources-401775.html)

Comment: how about reverse the lines.

Comment: split based on space and use array/list to reverse it. You need to reverse the words not just characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are not flushing the stream. A `BufferedXXXStream` has a *buffer*.

If you don't `close()` the stream or `flush()` it then the data stays in the buffer.

Why not use Java 8 higher order constructs?

```
final Path in = Paths.get("src", "file", "in.txt");
final Path out = Paths.get("src", "file", "out.txt");
try (
        final Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(in);
        final PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(out));
) {
    lines.
            map(l -> l.split(" ")).
            map(Arrays::asList).
            forEach(l -> {
                Collections.reverse(l);
                l.forEach(outputStream::print);
                outputStream.println();
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this in java 7 would be using try with resources.

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/file/in.txt"); FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("src/file/out.txt")) {
```

Note, a catch statement for this is optional. You don't need to use a try with resources on the buffered reader /writer in this sample because there parent class is being handled.

A try with resources will handle closing the stream if there is an error.

It is a good habit to flush the stream after every operation. Do not flush after ewery write as you lose the benefit of a buffered stream. Flush after every major write operation so you don't lose any data in case your program crashes.

Flushing after every write is like saving after typing every character when typing an essay.

Note this feature was added in java 7 so it will not work in java 6, if you need to support older releases you will need to manually close the stream.